# Login to Microsoft Graph API from Mac (Xamarin)

Tags: macos, xamarin.mac, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to connect my Mac App (written in c# / Visual Studio for Mac) to the Graph API from Microsoft.

On Windows, I can use the ADAL and perform an operation like:

```
        PublicClientApplication myApp = new PublicClientApplication(MYID);
        string Scope = "User.ReadBasic.All User.Read";
        var result = await myApp.AcquireTokenAsync(Scope.Split(' '));
        return result.AccessToken;
```

While the same approach on Mac results in a "not implemented" exception.

I tried several ways like ADFSApi and MicrosoftLiveConnectApi from SimpleAuth but with no luck.

Does anybody know how to perform this Auth? On the other hand, I find very often guides that uses the browser... How can I read the response from the browser from App with the Code to obtain the token?

------------- UPDATE ---------------------

After hours of work, I implemented an alternative flow. Basically when the login button is pressed, I perform a Segue to a Window with only the WebView in it.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var webView = new WebKit.WebView(this.MainView.Frame, "officeWebView", "noName");

        webView.MainFrameUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state=ltxzlgtghhxgpwuh&client_id=[MYID]&response_type=code&scope=User.ReadBasic.All%20User.Read&redirect_uri=msal[MYID]://auth";
        webView.FinishedLoad += (sender2, e) =>
        {
            var url = ((WebKit.WebView)sender2).MainFrameUrl;
        };

        this.MainView.AddSubview(webView);
    }
```

At the end of login, the system prompt me a message like "There is no App to open MSAL[MYID] etc. So I add the "bind" in the info.plist

[image]

Where actually the URL Scheme is MSAL[MYID].

I implemented the OpenUrls method in the AppDelegate.cs

```
 public override void OpenUrls(NSApplication application, NSUrl[] urls)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TEST!!!");
        foreach(var url in urls)
            Console.WriteLine(url);

        base.OpenUrls(application, urls);
    }
```

But it seems that the OpenUrls is NEVER triggered (never printed a single line, never hit a breakpoint).

What's wrong? And, if I successfully made it this way, how can I move to IMPLICIT grant in order to keep my app-secret secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact details for your situation. But you can use a WebKit.WebView

In my case I use facebook login through my own website and pass the facebook token back through a redirect url.

Assign FrameLoadDelegate

```
webView.FrameLoadDelegate = this;
webView.MainFrameUrl = starturlhere;
```

Implement webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:

```
    [Export ("webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:")]
    public void FinishedLoad (WebKit.WebView sender, WebKit.WebFrame forFrame)
    {
        // page loaded
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FinishedLoad: "+sender.MainFrameUrl);

        var url = new NSUrl(sender.MainFrameUrl);
        var document = sender.MainFrameDocument;

        // check if this is the login result 
        // if not do nothing and return (login flow not done)
    }
```

Extract the required data from either the url or the loaded page

// UPDATE

IF not logging in through your own server. Set a redirect url for https://127.0.0.1 (or anything really) and intercept the redirect with one of these (check for the correct url):

```
        webView.ReceivedServerRedirectForProvisionalLoad += (object sender, WebFrameEventArgs e) => 
        {
            //e.ForFrame.ProvisionalDataSource.Request.Url;
        };

        webView.OnSendRequest += (WebView sender, NSObject identifier, NSUrlRequest request, NSUrlResponse redirectResponse, WebDataSource dataSource) => 
        {
            //request.Url;
        };
```

Comment: I'm trying to do so, and almost works. But in the last part of the login I start getting this error: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9800).
I already added into the info.plist all the flags to allow unsecure connection but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: allow unsecure connection on a login flow? But without more details it is hard to say. There are many posts on kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL but thats a different question.

Comment: i solved the error adding a REDIRECT_URI to the OAuth Auth call. Now the system should call back my OpenUrls method but it's not triggered. I'm adding stuff the question, in order to make it easier to understand

Comment: Maybe you can redirect to 127.0.0.1 localhost and capture the url from the webview. No OpenUrls needed then.

Comment: The redirect_uri must be SSL, so if I put https:// localhost I get the old error again: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9800)

Comment: worked like a charm! Thank you!
P.S.: I tried to build a brand new project and the "info.plist" stuff etc worked. So it must be related to other plugin or previous app config